# Double tooltip popup

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create custom tooltip. I am relatively new to HTML and CSS. The problem is that I followed tutorial about tooltips but I get double display of tooltip on hover. I see my custom tooltip and the stock one together. I wish to see only the custom one.

HTML:

```
<button class="tooltip" title="Site1 tooltip." id=main1 type="button" onclick="loadData(1)">
    <img src="Images/Icon.png" width="68" height="68"/>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}


.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found A solution!

Remove the title attribute - @Robert

And in css:

```
content: "My content";
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the title attribute, this is responsible for the standard tooltip.

Comment: Ok, but where I put my tooltip text?

Comment: It depends. I don't know your custom tooltip logic, usually you put it in a custom attribute that gets read by your tooltip JS, or you derive the tooltip text from the id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have resort to javascript.

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) has a [tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) plugin, which is very flexible and customizable. You may also have to lear some javascript, and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) if you are new to web programming. But the good news is that jQuery is designed for simplicity.

The root of the problem is the title attribute, that causes the double-title display.

Answer (score 0):

http://ransandeep.blogspot.in/2010/04/light-weight-popup-using-css-and.html

it has full description to create a tooltip window/popup window.

the blog contains details for popup window so event is Click event.
you may change the event to onhover or onmousemove/mouseout in place of 
`onclick="HideDiv('DivPopUp');"`
`onclick="ShowDiv('DivPopUp')"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

do not use Title as it was for the standard HTML tooltip, use data-original-title instead

```
 <i class="fas fa-info-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="test"></i>
```